# What happened to the embryos that Nedry stole?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-park

When Denis Nedry is attempting to escape the island with the embryos in *Jurassic Park*, he drops them and they're covered in mud.

What happens to those embryos?

Comment: They will probably not hatch since it's to cold outside. They will be buried in the ground and mud.....forever...

Comment: @Decypher I think so too. You should copy this as an answer.

Comment: You seem [very angry](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/50740/7812) about the answers you've had. Is there anything you feel should have been addressed?

Comment: Even if, in a massive pseudo-science stretch, they could hatch, they're locked inside a sealed canister and will die.

Answer (score 6):

First off, the embryos aren't viable without a host. In the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park_(novel)), there's mention of both "artificial wombs" and a material used to make artificial eggshell that houses the embryos. Without such a mechanism, they'll just die.

> Then, in 1987, InGen bought an obscure company called Millipore
> Plastic Products in Nashville, Tennessee. This was an agribusiness
> company that had recently patented a new plastic with the
> characteristics of an avian eggshell. This plastic could be shaped
> into an egg and used to grow chick embryos. Starting the following
> year, InGen took the entire output of this millipore plastic for its
> own use.”

We know from Dodgson's chat with Nedry that the coolant will only last 36 hours. During that time, the island was evacuated and **the embryos weren't recovered, so they died in the can.**

> **DODGSON:** *The bottom screws open; it's cooled and compartmentalized inside.  They can even check it if they want.  Press
> the top. ... There's enough coolant gas for thirty-six hours.*

We see that **the can is sufficiently advanced as to resist cursory inspection** from customs. It even sprays foam. In the novel, the can went into his bag and that's the last time we see it. In the film he drops it, but the result is much the same. In the unlikely event that the can was ever recovered from the mud (or the car) it would simply be classified as household waste.

---

In [Jurassic Park: The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park:_The_Game), the Barbasol can acts as [the Macguffin](https://youtu.be/HTyo-Bkfq00?si=1ZCQ7_G3s79zHtNS&t=641).

Per the [Jurassic Park Wiki](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Barbasol_can):

> The game resolves the loose end of what happened to the can after
> Nedry's death, after it was covered in mud. Nima Cruz and Miles
> Chadwick, two BioSyn employees, decide to go in after Nedry when he
> does not show up at the East Dock. After finding the Jeep, putting
> together clues of how Nedry met his doom, and recovering the Barbasol
> can from the mud, the pair is attacked by a pack of dilophosaurs. They
> attack Miles, who is subsequently killed, while Nima grabs the can and
> escapes the scene. It stayed in Nima's possession until it is stolen
> by Billy Yoder while she is unconscious. Yoder insists on keeping it
> in his possession until they both leave the island. Eventually, Nima
> gets the can back after an unexpected turn of events, only for it to
> either be trampled by the Tyrannosaurus rex or left to decay on the
> island, depending on which ending the player chooses.

Answer (score 1):

In the spin-off show *[Jurassic World: Camp Cretaceous](https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/Jurassic_World:_Camp_Cretaceous#Season_5)*, Dodgson mounts an expedition to Jurassic Park and [stumbles across the Barbasol can](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLcL2dub8DU), along with the intact embryo vials.

[image]

The can is then seen on his shelf in the film *Jurassic World: Dominion*. It's not clear whether the embryos contained any useful biological specimens after more than two decades buried in mud and sand, but the can itself apparently has some sentimental value for him.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is no official statement about this, these are just the logical options:

- They will probably not hatch since it's to cold outside. They will be buried in the ground and mud ... forever... .
- The embryos will get found by another dinosaur and get eaten.
- I doubt it would be warm enough for them to hatch, but it's an option :)

The first option is most likely what happened. Nobody will go look for them either, if the people from the Jurrasic Park project would return to get some more embryos, they would get them from the facilities since there are still some left. But due to there being no more power, all the embryos will die and rot and will become useless.